# Is it possible to assign a function pointer before calling a function?

Tags: c

Whenever any program is executed, the `main` function is executed first and then other functions are called to RAM. In most of the programs that use function pointers, I encountered the code below right after opening flower bracket of the `main` function:

```
p = f1;  //p is function pointer and f1 is function name
```

How is it possible to assign the address of a function to a function pointer, when the function has not been called to RAM yet?
Or does the below code

```
p = f1;
```

mean calling a function also?

Comment: called to RAM... what?

Comment: Functions are not called anywhere. They are called in place.

Comment: I think they mean "How can one assign a function pointer if the actual position of a function in virtual memory will be determined at run-time?", but that's a shot in the dark. I guess that's OP's understanding and question. Is that right, OP?

Comment: All functions are (normally) *loaded* to memory when your program starts. Calling a function is not related to and happens after loading it to memory.

Comment: I got to know through a video that functions get loaded to memory only when main function calls it.

Comment: Do not learn C with videos.

Comment: " functions get loaded to memory only when main function calls it" -->  That may be true with a select C implementation.  Yet that is an implementation detail.  `p=f1;` is fine. -based on the _virtual machine_.  A compliant implementation must support that code - somehow.

Comment: @Mubashirakhanum: Beware of learning C from random videos - a lot of people *think* they know the language better than they really do.

Comment: If your particular implementation is one that only loads a function into memory when needed, then the assignment of the pointer will make it needed, or else your compiler is out of spec.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question:

First question:
you can assign the function pointer with the function address without prior call to this function.

The second question:
It only assigns the function pointer `p` with the address (reference) of the function `f1`. It does not do anything else, especially it does not call any functions.

The third question from the comment. The function will usually will not be linked into the executable file if the function is not used anywhere in your program. But the assignment of the function pointer is one of such a "uses" and it will be linked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the concept of virtual, or program address as opposed to physical address.   RAM uses physical addresses.  A program uses virtual addresses, which are selected by the linker (ld, in unixi).   When the Operating System loads a page of a program into RAM, it creates a translation between the virtual address and the physical address.   When an opcode references memory, the CPU uses this translation to retrieve the appropriate RAM location.

summary:
A program knows all of its static virtual addresses before it starts.
The stack and dynamically allocated addresses are calculated and managed in the program.
The Operating System / CPU dynamically and transparently translate these virtual addresses into physical ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `p` as a global variable and initialize it to `f1`, provided the declaration of `f1` is in scope and has a prototype compatible with the definition of `p`. Initializing a pointer does not call the function, nor does it access the memory where the function code is located. It just stores the value of its address to the location of the pointer variable.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void say_hello(void) {
    printf("Hello world\n");
}

void (*p)(void) = say_hello;

int main(void) {
    (*p)();
    return 0;
}
```

The way code is *called into RAM* is an operating system issue, you can completely disregard this concept when programming in C.